# Difficult PHP/MySQL code

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 DB tables

1. users(userid etc)
2. friends(friendid,userid,friendsuserid)
3. updates(updateid, userid, update)

Basically I've coded a script that lets you update your profile with activity(like a status) and able to become friends with one another(using friends table, userid + friendsuserid = they friends)

However, when it comes to the home page displaying these updates, I can display mine(user logged in) totally fine, but the friends updates dont show.

I'm having problems with it as it seems a lot of querys need to happen, to select the user logged in the friends table and get their friends userid... then its another select query to select all the statuses with the user logged in id and the friends id. then another select query to select the information from all the users profile to display their name alongside the status.

At the moment, I can only think of looping the query and putting id's in an array, then putting the array into a select query for the friends updates and displaying them.. is there a better way? code is a mess lol and im getting confused with the amount of querys(basically 2 of each for the friends and for the user logged in) must be an easier way lol

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into JOINs and subqueries.
You should make a "subquery" -  select the user that is logged in then join on the friends table (to get all of the friends userIds) and then use that list to filter in updates table

[basic joins explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

[subquery info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get updates of user and updates of user's friends by doing something similar to this.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM updates u INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT friendsuserid as userid FROM friends WHERE userid = [youruserid]
    UNION
    SELECT userid FROM friends WHERE friendsuserid = [youruserid]
   )f
ON u.userid = f.userid
```

Comment: That works a dream, however how would I be able to select all the user profiles of only the friends like userid etc? as now i've got all the updates of the friends, I'll need to get user info on the users table to use with the updates for links and names etc. Also, would you be able to explain that query?

Comment: Just inner join f with user tables (look up inner joins).

Comment: explain the query, f is subselect that returns userids of people who are friends of userid and UNION with userids of people who userid is friend of.

Comment: I've replied, not sure how this site works with regards to notifications